# Fail to Generate Signed APK : java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry

Tags: android

I had trying to build my android project. when I rebuild project, there are just few warning with no error. but when i try to generate signed apk, it shows the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllReleaseClassesForMultiDex'. java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/ConnectionClosedException.class

i know ConnectionClosedException.class is duplicate in my dependencies, but i can't find it. any body know how to deal with this problem? the dependencies in build.gradle is as follow:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.5'
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.0.0'
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')}
```

thanks a lot~

2016.06.29
after i adjust the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.5'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'}
```

the error becomes:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'. >com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart$1.class
```

any one know how to check which dependent library conflicting with any other?

Comment: If I had to guess, it's in the OSGI or httpmime package, also, you don't need the v4 jar file... appcompat-v7 already includes that

Comment: Additionally, I highly doubt you need the entire play services dependency. Read here about selectively compiling what you actually need. This will reduce the time it takes to build your app and your final app size. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use Maven dependencies to prevent duplicates, so replace

```
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.jar')
```

with

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2'
```